# $(this) referring to first selector element in extended JQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery

This was a relatively difficult one to explain in the title, so this is a further explanation.

Say I extend JQuery by doing something like the following:

```
$.fn.extend({
    Example:function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html());
    }
});
```

And then I call that method on multiple elements with a single selector, eg:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".element").Example();
});
```

Where the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="element">Element 1</div>
<div class="element">Element 2</div>
```

The final product looks like this:

```
Element 1
Element 1
```

Obviously this is just a very simple example, but what would be the proper procedure to make each element reference itself. It seems strange, because when calling $(this).html("a change"); it is applying to each one, but when calling $(this).html() it seems to be referencing the first one it came across.

Have I got this all mixed up, would someone mind helping me get my head around this. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because `this` is a collection of all the elements in the selector. Getting the `html()` of a collection will only return the HTML of the *first* element in the set. Therefore your code sets the HTML of *all* elements to match the *first*.

To fix this you can either use an `each` call to change the context of `this` to each individual element:

```js
$.fn.extend({
  Example: function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).html() + ' foo');
    });
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".element").Example();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">Element 1</div>
<div class="element">Element 2</div>
```

Alternatively, you can provide a function to `html()` which will be applied to each element in turn:

```js
$.fn.extend({
  Example: function() {
    return $(this).html(function(i, html) {
      return html + ' foo';
    });
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".element").Example();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">Element 1</div>
<div class="element">Element 2</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic and VERY quick answer. Testing proves you are correct and it makes perfect sense. I was thinking the extended method would be individually called on each element returned from the selector. But this makes much more logical sense. Thank you, no need to wait for other answers!

Comment: The solution is simple then and works with my project. Just wrap everything inside the extended method with: $(this).each(function(){ /* method content */ });

Comment: No problem, glad to help! One thing I just added to the answer was a `return` statement so that you can chain after calling `Example()`

Comment: That's a very good point, I'm learning a lot today :p thanks again!